# i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A

Tags: syslog, vga, i915, drm

This is an error against the internal Intel i915 VGA video card.

I see the error on a daily basis in syslog, even though I use the Nvidia card in my system.

To see if you have the problem, do the following simple search:

```
grep -i atomic /var/log/syslog*
```

You **may** get something similar to:

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=148972 end=148973) time 1174 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1041, end 1120
```

You've got the problem.

Comment: What version of kernel you use? I think this error is already reported here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/2215

Comment: @Thedemon007 I currently use kernel 6.2.0-35. In reading at the link you provided, kernel 6.5.7 still has the problem. Thanks for your contribution though :-)